# Copying data from a pivot table only when a new one appears

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Everyday in vba, I download a sheet containing data which I use to refresh the pivot table.
In the pivot table, the data from the day appears with the date of the day above  and I would like to copy it automatically.
There is an exception for the weekend where the saturday, sunday and monday appears automatically.

How can i do this ?

[image: the pivot table]

I think I need to adapt this code but it isn't dynamic

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been 
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```

I tried to adapt the code abose but this isn't dynamic

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Instead, post the code itself so that it can be copy/pasted.

Comment: sorry here is the code :


Copier
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been 
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

End If
End Sub

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. As you can see, they cannot be properly formatted. Instead, edit your question to include the code.

Comment: it's done, sorry for the inconvience :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copyRea()

Dim wb As New Workbook
Dim ws As New Worksheet

Dim newdata As Range
Dim rg As Range
Dim n As Date
Dim row_val As Integer

Set wb = activeworbooks.Select
Set ws = activeworksheet.Select
Set rg = ws.PivotTable("Rea").Columnfield("Date début").Range
Set n = Now()

If Year(rg) = Year(n) And Month(rg) = Month(n) And Day(rg) = Day(n) Then 
 'if the data of the day is found in the pivot table

 'go to the previous column and copy the data of the fields : Total Cat Total Hors Cat
     Set newdata = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                Before:=Cells(row_val), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False)
newdata.Copy
   

Else

Exit Sub


End If

End Sub
```

I tried some coding

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).